# Why I can't call methods for certain classes before creating instances? Understanding the logic

Tags: python, class, object, methods, instance

I have two example to help you understand what I mean

Example1 works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x_grid = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
df = pd.read_excel('somefile.xlsx').dropna()
```

I called the method dropna() on the instance of a DataFrame object when creating it.

Example2 does not work:

```
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kde import KDEUnivariate
kde = KDEUnivariate(df).fit().evaluate(x_grid)
```

To make it work I need to create the instance of the Class first like this:

```
kde = KDEUnivariate(df)
```

And then call the methods one at a time

```
kde.fit()
grid = kde.evaluate(x_grid)
```

What is the logic behind this?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x_grid = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
df = pd.read_excel('somefile.xlsx').dropna()

from statsmodels.nonparametric.kde import KDEUnivariate
kde = KDEUnivariate(df).fit().evaluate(x_grid)
```

then you actually pass the **return value** of fit() method, which is `'NoneType'`.

The same if you did this:

```
kde = KDEUnivariate(df)
kde = kde.fit()

grid = kde.evaluate(x_grid)
```

But you don't want this.

You want a **instantiated**, then **fitted**`KDEUnivariate()` object.
Then evaluate it.

That is why the appropriate way of calling mechanism is as follows:

```
kde = KDEUnivariate(df)
kde.fit()

grid = kde.evaluate(x_grid)
```

In this situation the `KDEUnivariate()` **instance**'s `evaluate()` method works with the `KDEUnivariate()` **instance** itself, and with it's fitted parameters, **not** the **return value** of `KDEUnivariate()` **instance**'s `fit()` method.

Comment: ok so the reason is because the fit() method does not return anything but actually modify the instantiated object? that makes sense. Thank you very much. I don't understand why one would write a method that works like this though. It is not practical in my opinion. You need 3 lines of code.

Comment: @gioxc88 this is a Scipy tradition and though first I found weird, I realized that the logic behind the scene inherit from its math i.e. when you try to find a function which is fits to the dataset i.e. input then you actually try to find its proper parameters which it can do with.

Comment: @gioxc88 the code is more transparent this way in 3 lines, which is often much more important.

Comment: I understand it, nevertheless I think it is a bit redundant. I come from sklearn where methods return the object itself instead of None and in my opinion it is better that way. Anyway thank you very much for the crystal clear explanation!!!